# Unable to load image from device using glide in Android 10 (Q)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

**Glide** is not loading image picked from gallery.
It always show following error despite giving write and read permission.

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_20200120103701_3365226945725752825.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Comment: Please provide extra information. This question is too poor. Such question often has a lot of negative marks.

Comment: Please check answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this line android manifest

android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the related uri, not the path,

```
 Glide.with(context).load(model.photoUri).into(image)
```

By this you don't need to add

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

in your Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

No Gallery app will have given you that File path.

So you have been messing around with something like getRealPathFromUri().

That will not do on Q as nobody has access to that Pictures path.

Better use the obtained uri directly.

You should do that below Q too.

Comment: i am used direct path like below  but not working  no error but cannot showing in image view ```file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20200319_162840.jpg```

Answer (score 0):

Make file instance and pass file's uri that you want to load into ImageView
You can also use RequestListener to trace the error in case of failure

```
 Glide.with(context)
        .load(new File(fileUri.getPath())) // Uri of the picture
        .into(imageview)
        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            Log.e("xmx1","Error "+e.toString());
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
            Log.e("xmx1","no Error ");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Make sure you have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

inside your application tag ```

```
<application
android:name=".App"
android:allowBackup="false"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
... >
```